# Zend Framework 2 - Uploadify fails with HTTP response 302

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, zend-framework2, uploadify

I'm trying to get `Uploadify` to work but I always get a http status code `302`.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'swf'      : '<?php echo $this->basePath('/swf/uploadify.swf') ?>',
        'uploader' : '<?php echo $this->url('my-module', array('action'=>'uploadify')) ?>',
        'debug': true,
        'preventCaching'  : false
    });
```

When I call my action via the browser it works. When I call the swf via browser, I get a 200 - so it works as well.

I checked the uploadify-forum but their solutions either don't work or are related to ZF1 specifica...

Comment: You know, what "302" means? Thats nothing bad by itself ;)

Comment: I know that but it's not working and interpreted as error. Therefore it's quite bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem just using another uploader. Flash uploading is out-of-date anyway so I just used: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

If you take the basic install it just works (I kept the uploadify upload function). The only drawback is that you have to design the uploading kinda manually... but not that tricky if you are familiar with Bootstrap and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

this is a flash cookie bug,the solution is restart session

note: I only tested on unix/linux

```
 class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onApplicationPreDispacth'), 100);

    }

    public function onApplicationPreDispacth($e)
    {
         $session_name = session_name();

         if (isset($_POST[$session_name])) {
              session_destroy();
              session_id($_POST[$session_name]);
              session_start();
         }
    }
```

Priority of this function must high than a one you posted a 302 redircti

and in javascript:

```
$('#file_upload2').uploadify({
        'buttonText' : 'select files',
        'swf'      : '/static/lib/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '/service/upload',
        'auto'     : true,
        'formData' : voice : {"<?php echo session_name();?>" : "<?php echo session_id(); ?>",'source':'voice'}
        } 
        // Put your options here
    });
```

[use uploadify in zend framework 2](http://www.lijianxuan.com/post/2014/use-uploadify-in-zend-framework2-no-http302-error) I worte this just then